# Deja Dup Backup to Cd/Dvd Possible or Not?

Tags: backup, dvd, cd, deja-dup

I started to use Linux/Ubuntu 12.04 last week. I'm a new comer. I liked this O.S. But I have a question which I couldn't find the answer here and by google search.
The question is "Can I get scheduled backups to Cd/Dvd with Deja Dup software on Ubuntu O.S?"
The firm that I'm working has a 700mb folder to be backed up. The files in the folder can be changed by any user during the day. So we need to backup the whole 700mb folder each day. The best solution comes to my mind is that taking the back-up to a Cd or Dvd. It will be very easy if this back-up procedure is scheduled by a program. Do you have any answers?

Thanks in advance
Altan from Turkey/Istanbul

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You might be better off using a synchronizing utility such as Unison or Conduit instead. Both programs have been great for me in the past. If you were wanting a CD backup you'd be better off with Unison, though I doubt you'd get automatic backups.

What about syncing to the cloud?? if you only need 700mb per day you can get free licenses for dropbox/box.net etc for that.

Answer (score 0):

To backup through `deja-dup` to a CD or DVD, change the backup location to `local folder` and select `choose a location` (approximate translations), then choose your CD/DVD in the location.

Thanks, mjchopperboy